# Как перенаправить PendingIntent из Notification в уже открытое приложение

Tags: android

Мое приложение запускает по будильнику определенное уведомление. Оно висит в левом углу экрана, а когда по нему кликнут открывает мое приложение.

Проблема в том что, если мое приложение уже открыто то оно открывает еще одну копию. Получается, что два одинаковых параллельно работающих приложения висят в памяти.

Как сделать, чтоб уведомление знало открыто приложение или нет? К примеру, когда получаешь уведомление от gmail и, не кликая на уведомления, открываешь gmail, то уведомление исчезает.

singleTop из manifest не вариант. Да, он не плодит новые копии приложения, но и не юзает, ту которая была открыта до того, как я нажал на уведомление.

Answer (score 2):

Это регулируется флагами `PendingIntent` - если память не изменяет можно применить `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`

[Почитайте доки](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html)

Comment: Собственно, эти флаги заменяют одно уведомление на другое или вовсе его стирают. Теперь с gmail понятно, спасибо) Не понятно другое: как по клику на уведомление открыть уже открытую программу.

Answer (score 0):

android:launchMode="singleTask" в манифесте.

Не обратил внимание на него вначале(